# How to port the code of an application on Windows Mobile 6.5 to Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have an application running successfully on Windows Mobile 6.5. Is it possible to port that application to Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 2):

If the application is written with .NET  you should be able to port over your business logic.  The biggest change you will have to make it rewriting your UI, since in Windows Phone 7 you must write the UI using Silverlight or XNA.

If your application is written in C++ you will have to rewrite it all.